# How do I manually set the active image for jquery-lightbox?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, lightbox

I am trying to create a photo viewer in Ruby on Rails using [jquery-lightbox](https://github.com/krewenki/jquery-lightbox). You can see the design of it in the image below.

You click on the smaller images to have the selected image appear in the large space above. If you click the large image, you can view a lightbox slideshow of all the images at their originally uploaded resolution.

I have all of this working so far, but **I need the lightbox to start at the currently selected image, rather than always starting at the first image**. I've tried calling the changeImage function (returns TypeError) and changing the activeImage property (does nothing).

How can this be done?

Here is the code I'm using, which is currently all in my show.html.erb:

```
<a href="<%= @actor.avatar.url(:large) %>" onclick="javascript:setActiveImage();" class="lightbox" title="<%= @actor.name %>" rel="actor"><%= image_tag @actor.avatar.url(:slide), :id => "actor_headshot", :alt => @actor.name %></a>

<% @actor.photos.each do |photo| %>
  <a href="<%= photo.photo.url(:large) %>" class="lightbox" rel="actor"></a>
<% end %>

<div id="actor_photos">
  <div id="actor_photo_list">
  <% @photos.each_with_index.map do |photo, index| %>
      <a href="#" onclick="javascript:swapHeadshot('<%= photo.url(:slide) %>', <%= index %>);"><%= image_tag photo.url(:thumb), :class => "actor_photo_list_item" %></a>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<script language="JavaScript">
  $('.lightbox').lightbox();

  var _am = 0;

  function swapHeadshot(source, index)
  {
    $('#actor_headshot').attr('src', source);
    _am = index;
  }

  function setActiveImage()
  {
    $('.lightbox').lightbox.activeImage = _am; // has no effect
    //$('.lightbox').lightbox({activeImage:_am}); // has no effect
    //$('.lightbox').lightbox.changeImage(_am); // returns TypeError
  }
</script>
```

[image: Photo viewer]

Comment: Post the JavaScript you are using to currently try to change the light box to a certain image, and let us know which line is giving you the 'TypeError'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default jQuery Lightbox comes with prev/next buttons. You might wanna take a look into that code an create a function based on either one of them since they most likely will provide you an answer.

Inside the code it says:

```
$('#lightboxImage').attr('src', opts.imageArray[opts.activeImage][0])width(newWidth).height(newHeight);
resizeImageContainer(newWidth, newHeight);
```

I think that's the code you're looking for.

// Edit: made the same mistake as the one above, except he's given an answer already.

Comment: Dang. Thought there would already be something built in to do this. I'll try this approach and probably post the code to github or something.

Answer (score 0):

`changeImage` sounds like the name of a function, but your code is:

```
$('.lightbox').lightbox.changeImage =(_am); //tries to change a function variable to a number
```

Are you sure it shouldn't be:

```
$('.lightbox').lightbox.changeImage(_am); //calls the function passing a variable
```